# Eclipse can't debug android application on Samsung galaxy S4

Tags: android, eclipse, samsung-mobile

i've installed Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.14.0 driver in my computer. in my device i checked enable debug and allow unknown source. When i ran my application from eclipse, eclipse show a popup to select target device. i saw the device XXXXX with Offline state but run button still disable.

Comment: Did you try cycling adb? (adb kill-server adb start-server)

Comment: Try these Restart adb by issuing 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb start-server' at a cmd prompt
Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone
Rebooting the phone in 95 % cases it does work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is device is unauthorised  for USB debugging. Ideally a pop up should appear on the device asking to provide permission for USB debugging. Select Allow always for this computer and click OK. This will solve the offline issue.

If the pop up does not come up when you plug the device to computer. Open adb command prompt and run

**adb usb** in command prompt this will reboot android adb usb listner which will force the pop up to come on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the method I did was:

1. Turn off your GS4
2. Turn on your device to Recovery Mode (Vol up + power button)
3. Open Device Manager in you computer
4. Select `Action->Scan` for Hardware changes
5. There will be an icon marked with red exclamation point symbol
6. Right-click the `icon -> Update Driver Properties -> "Search automatically`. Your computer will download the drivers from the internet and update your computer.
7. Your phone is still in recovery mode, select reboot
8. You can check DDMS on eclipse if it is there.